# How to use dynamic map name in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, dynamic

I want to create a new map every time the button is pressed.
I want the names of the maps to be regular.
I tried using ${} in the map name but it doesn't seem to work.
is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think you want this, but you don't.  Information and meta-information should remain separate.  Very likely, a Map of Maps will accomplish everything you want with dynamic names.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use the sprintf function:

String mapName = sprintf("map_%d", mapNumber);

2. Use string interpolation:

String mapName = "map_${mapNumber}";

3. Use a template string:

String mapName = `map_${mapNumber}`;